# In IDA Pro what is '::lower16::' in the 2nd ARM operand do?

Tags: objective-c, arm, ida

E.G I have this:

```
MOVW R1, #(:lower16:(selRef_stringWithUTF8String_ - 0xbeee)
MOV  R6, R0
MOVT.W R1, #(:upper16:(selRef_stringWithUTF8String_ - 0xbeee)
```

There is :lower16: and :upper16: before the address of the operand. I presume its because its in thumb mode and the size of the pointer to the string is too large so its fetching lower and  upper portions? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just as you guessed. In Thumb-2, when loading a 32-bit number it is often using a MOV/[MOVT](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjagdjbf.html) instruction pair, e.g.

```
MOVW   R1, #0x1234          ; Set the value of R1.      R1 is now 0x1234
MOVT.W R1, #0x5678          ; Set the top-16 bit of R1. R1 is now 0x56781234.
```

IDA Pro recognized that the combined immediate value matches the address of a selector, and uses the `:lower:` and `:upper:` syntax to indicate that the value is split into two 16-bit parts.